# Omit language preVar for RealURL 2.x with multidomain-multilanguage setup?

Tags: typo3-6.2.x, realurl

In a TYPO3 6.2.30 site, I updated RealURL 1.x to 2.2.1.

It works fine, but it is a multilanguage-multidomain site that *doesn't* require the language prefix after the domain.

Before I had

```
www.germandomain.ch/seite
www.frenchdomain.ch/page
```

Now I get

```
www.germandomain.ch/de/seite
www.frenchdomain.ch/fr/page
```

The old paths are still working as an alternative though.

**How can I omit the parameter from the URL for both languages** - is that still possible with RealURL 2?

Below are the relevant configuration snippets. I don't have domain records defined in the backend / pagetree.

```
'preVars' => array(
                    array(
                         'GETvar' => 'L',
                         'valueMap' => array(
                                            'de' => '0',
                                            'fr' => '1',
                                    ),
                         //'valueDefault' => 'de',
                         'noMatch' => 'bypass',
                    ),
                  array(
                            'GETvar' => 'no_cache',
                            'valueMap' => array(
                                'no_cache' => 1,
                            ),
                            'noMatch' => 'bypass',
                    ),
            ),
```

and

```
 $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DOMAINS'] = array(
 'encode' => array(
     array(
         'GETvar' => 'L',
         'value' => '',
         'ifDifferentToCurrent' => true,
         'useConfiguration' => '_DEFAULT',
         'urlPrepend' => 'https://www.germandomain.ch',
     ),
     array(
         'GETvar' => 'L',
         'value' => '0',
         'ifDifferentToCurrent' => true,
         'useConfiguration' => '_DEFAULT',
         'urlPrepend' => 'https://www.germandomain.ch',
     ),
     array(
         'GETvar' => 'L',
         'value' => '1',
         'ifDifferentToCurrent' => true,
         'useConfiguration' => '_DEFAULT',
         'urlPrepend' => 'https://www.frenchdomain.ch',
     ),
 ),
 'decode' => array(
     'www.germandomain.ch' => array(
         'GETvars' => array(
             'L' => '0',
         ),
         'useConfiguration' => '_DEFAULT',
     ),
     'www.frenchdomain.ch' => array(
             'GETvars' => array(
             'L' => '1',
         ),
         'useConfiguration' => '_DEFAULT',
     ),
 ),
);
```

and in TS

```
config {
    sys_language_uid = 0
    linkVars = L
    language = de
    locale_all = de_DE.utf-8
    htmlTag_langKey = de
    #defaultGetVars.L = 0
}

[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
config {
    sys_language_uid = 1
    language = fr
    locale_all = fr_FR.utf-8
    htmlTag_langKey = fr
    #defaultGetVars.L = 1
}
[global]
```

Comment: once clear all **realUrl** tables data... after check

Comment: I do that all the time – manually or with realURL clearcache

Comment: "I don't have domain records defined in the backend / pagetree." -- Most likely, this is the problem...